# Reshaping a cell array in matlab

Tags: matlab

Hi I have a cell array which is called `vector`, with dimensions 69083x2 , now i want to reshape this cell array to 3212762x2, but reshape(vector,3212762,2) does not work. I get this error:

> To RESHAPE the number of
>   elements must not change.

Can anyone tell me how I can do this ?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean you wish to make the cell array larger? `reshape` is to store the same elements in a different 'shape', for eg., a 3x2 cell array as a 6x1 cell array - note that the total number of elements remains 6 in both cases.

If you wish to enlarge the cell array, just assign something to the last element of the enlarged cell array like so:

```
vector(3212762, 2) = {[]}
```

Now `vector` would be of size 3212762x2.

Comment: I want to make it larger, the values can't be erased .

Comment: Yes, the statement I gave would do exactly that - the existing values will remain where they are, and only the new cells will be empty.

Comment: Okay, though I get this error : Assignment has more non-singleton rhs
dimensions than non-singleton subscripts

Comment: Are you sure your `vector` is a cell array? Perhaps it's a matrix, in that case try vector(3212762, 2) = 0 instead.

Comment: Pretty sure :P (I get the error 'Conversion to cell from
double is not possible.' if I try that). I added a screenshot of my workspace etc

Comment: @Ojtwist Please check the edit, I forgot to put the empty matrix [] within the cell brackets {}, and was too lazy to test the code. :) The current statement works in my Matlab, tested.

Answer (score -2):

Just like sundar mentioned

```
vector(3212762, 2) = 0
```

will give you 3212762x2 matrix with the new rows assigned to 0.